# searching classes in an array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, search

I have an array (`Items`) which holds lots of instances of a class (`Item`).

`Item` has 2 properties, a Group and an ID.

there may be more than `Item` in the array(`Items`) that have the same Group and ID properties.

How do I "search"/get the first `Item` which matches a specified Group and/or ID

Something like:
`Item.getbygroup([group])` which returns an `item`

EDIT: And what would let me find the second one? So start searching for a point in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ:

where group and id are some variables to compare to

```
var item = Items.Where(x => x.Group == group || x.ID == id).First();
```

Comment: what do you mean legal? (beside the fact it's not VB)

Comment: Sure it is, the syntax just needs to be converted to VB, i.e. something like (untested): `Dim item = Items.Where(Function(x) x.Group = group OrElse x.ID = id).First()`

Comment: @Jonathan: I mean exactly the fact that it's not legal VB.NET syntax.

Comment: @Heinzi: If it needs to be converted then your assertion ("[s]ure it is") is false.

Comment: ok, i don't understand what you mean by the whole legal thing. Is the code in Heinzi's comment correct/useable/proper/"legal"

Comment: btw you can do this without any addons/extensions/etc

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa.aspx). From the documentation:

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire Array.

Example:

To search by `Item.Group`:

```
Item firstItem = Array.Find(Items, Function(item as Item) item.Group = group);
```

To search by `Item.ID`:

```
Item firstItem = Array.Find(Items, Function(item as Item) item.ID = ID);
```

Responding to your edit:

> EDIT: And what would let me find the second one? So start searching for a point in the array

You could do this:

```
Dim matches as Item()
Dim secondItem as Item
matches = Array.FindAll(Items, Function(item as Item) item.Group = group)
If matches.Length >= 2 Then
    secondItem = matches(1)
Else
    'handle case where no second item
EndIf
```